# How to get my license.key after deleting it via Git

Tags: license

I purchased a Craft Client license for a staging server we have, which uses Git for deployment.

Unfortunately, I forgot to copy the license.key file to my local copy of the site before my last git push, and it got clobbered.

Is there a way to retrieve my license? I have contacted Craft support, which I assume is the only way to get it back, however if there is a way to get it back on my own that would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, contacting support@buildwithcraft.com is the only way to retrieve a lost `license.key` file.

In the future, once we add user accounts to buildwithcraft.com, we'll also be adding order and license management, so you'll be able to retrieve it from there as well.

I've responded to your ticket with your proper `license.key` file.